# ng-focus not working for <button> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**ng-focus** is not working for button in all the browsers, may I know if there is any other feature like **ng-focus for `<button>`**, as I need to add on attribute to button on focus event. I tried with `onfocus()` event as well.

Comment: Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/UTn5y/1196/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fecusa/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

just use `ng-focus` like this

```
<input type="button" ng-focus="vm.onFocus()" value='test'>
```

make sure you have the function exposed from your controller

```
app.controller('MainController', function(){

  this.onFocus = function(){

    console.log('focused');

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ng-focus will work as soon as you click the button this behavior is because of following reason

Focus event only trigger when mouse cursor is on that specific control as soon as you clicked  the button focus event trigger and then if you click on area other than button area then it will  trigger the ng-blur event 
If you want that event trigger as soon as mouse comes over button then you should use ng-mouseover for entering into button and ng-mouseleave for leaving the button

---

```
<div ng-app ng-init="focus=false;blur=false;active=false">
<button
tabindex="1" 
ng-class="{ myFocus: focus, myBlur: blur }"    
ng-mouseover="focus=true;blur=false;" 
ng-mouseleave="blur=true;focus=false;"
value="Click me"
>
Click me
</button>
```